# applyTransaction to add a row fails

Tags: datatable, row, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Adding row using applyTransaction

```
this.agGridOptions.api.applyTransaction({ add: [value], addIndex: this.rowData.length - 1 })
```

is failing for ag-grid (27.3.0/28.1.1) with the following stack -

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'some')
at SortService.sort (ag-grid-community.auto.esm.js:50571:35)
at SortStage.execute (ag-grid-community.auto.esm.js:50361:26)
at ClientSideRowModel.doSort (ag-grid-community.auto.esm.js:50011:24)
at ClientSideRowModel.refreshModel (ag-grid-community.auto.esm.js:49767:22)
at ClientSideRowModel.commonUpdateRowData (ag-grid-community.auto.esm.js:50205:14)
at ClientSideRowModel.updateRowData (ag-grid-community.auto.esm.js:50182:14)
at GridApi.applyTransaction (ag-grid-community.auto.esm.js:32024:43)
at GridApi.updateRowData (ag-grid-community.auto.esm.js:32041:21)
```

I could not find any reported issues for the above stack.

Any pointers on how to debug the issue?

Comment: In `SortService.sort` method I found only one call to `some`:
`var groupColumnsPresent = this.columnModel.getAllGridColumns().some(function (c) { return c.isRowGroupActive(); });`
Not that it sheds any light. Maybe you mess with columns?

Comment: It is a legacy code that I am working upon so do not know the complete details of the columns. But i started getting this problem after upgrading from v21 to v27.